# Eclipse - Git Commit and Push empty folder(s)

Tags: git, eclipse

I created local empty folder structure and I don't see folders in `Unstaged Changes` view

I can't commit and push folders to repository, why can't it be done in Eclipse?

In git command line I can `git add` empty folders

Comment: You cannot add empty folders from the command line. (The `git add` command itself does not object, but does nothing.)

Comment: @torek dup isn't answering in eclipse, but in CLI

Comment: It doesn't matter: the point is, you cannot add an empty folder. Eclipse or no eclipse, you cannot add an empty folder! (The submodule-with-nothing-in-it trick does work, however.)